# Docker Entrypoint Script Root Permission

Tags: docker, sh, chmod, keytool, chown

I have a Dockerfile that has 3 constraints:

1.) The final USER statement in the Dockerfile must be `USER tomcat` for security purposes (it is built off the tomcat:8.5.23-jre8-alpine image)

2.) It cannot run chmod on the `/root/` directory or the `$JAVA_HOME`

3.) It must be able to modify the `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security` directory within the entrypoint and not in the Dockerfile (as certificates are passed in on container startup)

As of now I have

```
FROM tomcat:8.5.23-jre8-alpine

#### OTHER IMAGE COMMANDS ####

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

RUN chown root:root /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod 4755 /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh

USER tomcat

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

I figured giving ownership of the file to root and chmod 4755 would allow the tomcat user to execute the entrypoint, but have entrypoint run as root so that it could modify the file system as it would like to. However, when I run this line in the entrypoint

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -import -alias ca_local -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts -storepass XXXXX -noprompt -trustcacerts -file /usr/local/tomcat/certificates/ca-local.cer
```

I get the following error:

```
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts (Permission denied)
```

It seems the entrypoint isn't actually running as root, as the chown/chmod would have implied. I know that all of my files are in the correct places because when I remove `USER tomcat` from the Dockerfile everything works fine. What am I missing in setting the permission of the entrypoint?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In these two steps:

```
RUN chown root:root /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 4755 /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
```

You are ensuring the your `entrypoint.sh` script is owned by `root`, and then you are attempting to set the `setuid` bit.  Unfortunately, this second step isn't going to work: you can't mark a shell script (or in fact any interpreted script) as `setuid`; the bit will simply be ignored. See, e.g, [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts).

But event if that worked, you would have another problem: your `ENTRYPOINT` script is responsible for handling any command passed into your container, either on the `docker run` command line or via the `CMD` directive in the Dockerfile.  If that `setuid` attempt worked, your `ENTRYPOINT` script would be running as root...which means you would end up running `catalina.sh run` as root, which means your `USER` directive is completely pointless.

You could get to the same place by simply dropping the `USER` directive, allowing the entrypoint to run as `root`, and then have your `ENTRYPOINT` script run the `CMD` as the `tomcat` user (e.g., using `su` or `sudo`):

```
FROM tomcat:8.5.23-jre8-alpine

#### OTHER IMAGE COMMANDS ####

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

And in `entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Do stuff as root here.
$JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -import -alias ca_local \
  -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts 
  -storepass XXXXX -noprompt -trustcacerts \
  -file /usr/local/tomcat/certificates/ca-local.cer

# Now run everything else as a non-root user
exec su - tomcat -c "$*"
```

This is a very common mechanism for handling initial setup tasks that must be run as root while running everything else as a non-root user.

There are still a number of problems here: the underlying `tomcat:8.5.23-jre8-alpine` doesn't have a `tomcat` user, and the scripts in `/usr/local/tomcat/bin` are only executable by `root`. So if you want this particular image to work with a non-root user you probably have a bunch of configuration changes to make first.

Comment: Many image builds use [gosu](https://github.com/tianon/gosu) instead of `su` or `sudo` to be more Docker compatible

Comment: `runuser` is a great choice if your distribution includes it in the base image.

Comment: Thank you! Great explanation, if I could give 2 upvotes I would. The Tomcat user configuration is in the #### OTHER IMAGE COMMANDS #### section, so I'll just run my CMD as the tomcat user from the entrypoint.